# Static Member Array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, linker, static-members

I've created a static member array in class named `GTAODV`.

```
static int numdetections[MAXNODES];
```

However, when I try to access this array within the class methods (examples below),

```
 numdetections[nb->nb_addr]++;
 for(int i=0; i<MAXNODES; i++) if (numdetections[i] != 0) printf("Number of detections of %d = %d\n", i, numdetections[i]);
```

the linker gives an error during compilation:

```
gtaodv/gtaodv.o: In function `GTAODV::command(int, char const* const*)':
gtaodv.cc:(.text+0xbe): undefined reference to `GTAODV::numdetections'
gtaodv.cc:(.text+0xcc): undefined reference to `GTAODV::numdetections'
gtaodv/gtaodv.o: In function `GTAODV::check_malicious(GTAODV_Neighbor*)':
gtaodv.cc:(.text+0x326c): undefined reference to `GTAODV::numdetections'
gtaodv.cc:(.text+0x3276): undefined reference to `GTAODV::numdetections'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Why does this happen?

Comment: Because your linker doesn't know the definition of `numdetections`.  Where are you using this variable, and where is the definition?

Comment: I have defined numdetections in the class GTAODV, and I am using it in the GTOADV member functions.

Comment: Provide the code example. Where *exaclty* you have defined `numdetections`?

Comment: You said you defined numdetections in class GTAODV - actually, you "declared" it. The definition is missing, which is why you are getting link errors. Also, you edited the original question so now the answers' context is missing.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

When this error occurs it is very likely that you forgot to define your static member. Assuming this within your class definition:

```cpp
class GTAODV {
public:
    static int numdetections[MAXNODES]; // static member declaration
    [...]
};
```

Within a a source file:

```cpp
int GTAODV::numdetections[] = {0}; // static member definition
```

Note the definition outside the declaration in the class.

**Edit** This should answer the question regarding the "why": static members can exist without the existence of a concrete object, i. e. you can use `numdetections` without instantiating **any** object of `GTAODV`. To enable this external linkage must be possible and thus a definition of the static variable must exist, for reference: [Static data members (C++ only)](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xlcpp8a.doc/language/ref/cplr038.htm).

Comment: You must place that definition in a cpp file so that it's only defined once.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly the reason of the error. Could you please explain why this happens? - I thought  that the memory is allocated for a static member array when it is declared. I do initialize static member values this way, but I didn't know how to initialize a static member array.

Comment: @zmccord Thanks for the hint, made an edit for clarification.

Comment: Objects with static storage duration need a definition in addition to a declaration, as per C++ language specifications. The comments show you which lines are declarations and which one is the definition. Memory is not "allocated" in the declaration, it is allocated in the definition. Although "allocate" is a bit misleading since it does not use the free store.